# Using multiple SQS queues on a single connection - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

I am trying to understand if my issue is a limitation with Laravel's logic or an issue in my config. I have this in my `queue.php` file

```
'connections' => [
    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'token' => env('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'),
        'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
    ],
],
```

Now, when I try to this command

```
 php artisan queue:work sqs --tries 3 --queue='high-priority'
```

I would expect it to process the outstanding jobs in the 'high-priority' queue, however instead it throws this exception

```
   ErrorException  : Undefined index: queue

  at {redacted}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/SqsConnector.php:26
    22|             $config['credentials'] = Arr::only($config, ['key', 'secret', 'token']);
    23|         }
    24|
    25|         return new SqsQueue(
  > 26|             new SqsClient($config), $config['queue'], $config['prefix'] ?? ''
    27|         );
    28|     }
    29|
    30|     /**
```

Now I can see that laravel is trying to construct a new SqsClient using the config value in key of `queue`, so in this case it seems that to use multiple queues here I would need to define an individual connection for every queue (which seems completely overkill).

So really, wondering if this is a limitation or if I misunderstand how the config is being passed into the construction of the SqsClient.

Comment: what happens if you put `=` between `--tries` and `3` such as `--tries=3`

Comment: This is not the issue, the issue lies with how laravel constructs the `SqsQueue` class

Comment: It is constructed in the expected way - if you want multiple sqs queues then you need multiple config for each queue. It is not specific to sqs - redis queues also configured in the same way.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification. Just don't see the point of having the `--queue` option exposed if you can only use one queue per connection.

Comment: it is used to decide which queue you want to `work` - if you have multiple options each queue will have different key name name and different `queue` key name like these https://prnt.sc/szn426 and you will use `php artisan queue:work --queue=mjolnir --tries=1` to process `mjolnir`

Comment: https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/master/Console/WorkCommand.php#L22 you may check here the options are provided

Comment: That't not the case though. If you look at how `SqsQueue` is being constructed, is passes in `$config['queue']` which is derived from the `queue.php` config file. In that case having the `--queue` option is meaningless, since in our case it just gets ignored anyway. Also notice how you have had to duplicate your config across the 5 connections you specify. What I am trying to say is that it makes so much more sense to define a `redis` connection and then use the `--queue` option to specify which of the 5 queues you want to work on, instead of pointlessly duplicating 90% of the config

Comment: @Harry10932  Were you able to use multiple sqs queue. I have the same scenario, want to set the priority of the queues as high, low and medium. How did you do it. Can you share some knowledge.